# Getting empty data in bar charts

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, bar-chart

I am using BarChart and getting values through api. When I fetch data from backend and its showing empty in the BarChart.

**Below is my Html code**

```
<div fxFlex.gt-sm="33.33%" fxFlex.gt-xs="50" fxFlex="100">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content>
        <canvas height="200" baseChart class="chart" [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions"
          [colors]="chartColors" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
// Bar
  barChartLabels: string[] = ['0-20', '21-40', '41-60', '61-80', '81-100'];
  barChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegend = true;
  barChartData: any[] = [{
    data: []
  }];
  barChartOptions: any = Object.assign({
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
          defaultFontColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)'
        },
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
          defaultFontColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)',
          zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)'
        },
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }, this.globalChartOptions);
```

**I am calling the api**

```
this.patientService.agecount().subscribe(res => {
            const agetest = JSON.stringify(res);
         console.log('agetesting' + agetest);
         this.agechart.push(res);
         console.log('testing' + this.agechart);
         this.agetest1();
        });

    agetest1() {
      this.databar = this.agechart;
      console.log('testing the data' + JSON.stringify(this.databar));
    }
```

**Below Image shows output**
[image]

I am new to the bar charts and i am spending so much time on that.Is any one help to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [update()](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html):

```
 this.databar.data.datasets[0].data = res;
 this.databar.update();
```

OR

```
this.databar.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push(res);
 });
 this.databar.update();
```

Comment: Can you please explain where should i inject the update function @Amy

Comment: Getting error while committing update().

Property 'data' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
Property 'update' does not exist on type 'any[]'.